# User Privileges not getting saved in vtiger CRM

Tags: vtiger

I have installed Vtiger CRM and i started working on it. I am trying to change the privileges for administrators and for other  profiles in **CRM Settings->Profiles** but nothing is getting saved after **WASP**, before that till **PBX Manager** its getting saved.

Someone please help me why this is happening. Its been 3 days am finding out the solution. But couldn't help. Please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, Somebody can help me in this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have Suhosin patch installed on your server? If yes the problem is **suhosin.request.max_array_depth** or **suhosin.request.max_vars**

Comment: No. There is no Suhosin installed in my server. Thats why i am not getting what to do :(. I can provide you the login details. , can you please help me. This is very important for me. Am stuck here :(. Please help me

Comment: Hey kindly help me in this please

Comment: Can you please provide me the e-mail id?

Answer (score 1):

It' usually has to be with php configuration, there's a option in the php.ini file: "max_input_vars", change the default value and increase it. I guess default it's to 1000, try 3000.

If you are using php 5.3, that option does not exist, just add it to the php.ini file